Readme style for Azure DevOps Pipelines
Basically I treat that article as my primary guideline to create pipelines according to the best practices. I have two specific questions about readme itself, because I added in many places serval explanation about what the pipelines does? What parameters defines? etc.
More less it look like that:
# This pipeline is used to deploy <app> application for ...
# Path: <path>
# https://<link>

# Stages and Jobs:
# 1. Approval Gate (DEV/PRD)
#    - Manual validation job for deployment approval
# 2. DEV/PRD Deployment
#    2.1. Version Check
#         - Checks current <app>version before deployment      
#    2.2. Deploying
#         - Runs ansible playbook for <app> installation
#         - Validates logs
#    2.3. Version Check
#         - Verifies <app>version after deployment

# Pipeline name using dynamic build number and date. 
# Second keyword determines if the latest Git commit is appended to the end of the run name
name: CD-$(rev:r)-JCR-$(Date:dd.MM.yyyy)
appendCommitMessageToRunName: false

# Disable automatic PR and commit triggers
trigger: none
pr: none

resources:
  repositories:
    # Main <app> repository containing application code
    - repository: <repo>
      type: git
      name: <name>
      ref: <ref>
      endpoint: <endpoint>
  pipelines:
    # Trigger on successful <app> pipeline completions
    - pipeline: <pipeline>
      source: '<source>'
      project: <project>
      trigger: true

# Variables loaded from external template
variables:
  - template: /<app>/pipelines/variables/variables.yml

# Pipeline parameters:
# - runOnProductionMode: Controls whether pipeline runs in production mode
#   When set to true: Enables production deployment steps
#   When set to false: Runs on DEV and than PRD deployment steps
parameters:
  - name: runInProduction
    displayName: 'Run in Production'
    type: boolean
    default: false
 # Rest of the code

In <> I use real names.
First question is about the documentation itself, are you using so descriptive style in your pipeline? My goal was to make it clear for anyone who want to use those pipelines.
Second, if your pipelines grows are you keep the documentation for pipelines (how does it works? etc.) in some kind for  readme in separate file where you keep your pipelines, or in corporate intranet on wiki? I would like to follow best practices about documentation also, I think that aspect is often omitted.

It's a good thing to document pipelines and templates but don't exaggerate with comments, as these tend to get obsolete soon and some things should be obvious from the code. See DO: Document Pipelines and Templates

It is done exactly based on that article :) So I try to add short description at the beginning, and explanation of parameters etc.

Regarding parameters, use the displayName to provide a very brief explanation of the parameters instead of using comments at the top - example: displayName: SSH service connection.

Clear, I will do like that, thank you :)
